# VMware Creating Windows Images through commandline

Tags: python

I have a ESX server and I'm using Vsphere client to connect to ESX, I have to create more than 100 of windows images, which would be a combination of Windows XP,Windows Server 2003, Windows 7 etc. It's very hard by manual work, So I want to create those images in an automated fashion, Can anyone help me with any commandline options or any modules which we can automate those work.

Comment: With the [vSphere PowerCLI](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/) it's simple to create new VMs from a Powershell prompt. Wrapped in a loop, you could spawn hundreds in no time.  Add in your PXE-booting Windows deployment options and you're almost done.  Without knowing more about your environment, it's tough to give specific enough advice to be helpful.

Comment: While Creating Image in VMware ex.Winxp; requires user interaction for admin password and timezones etc. How it is handled in PowerCLI ?

Comment: The creation of the VM object and the scripted install of Windows are two separate processes. You'll want to research ["Windows unattended setup"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699026.aspx).  Our deployments go: 1.) PowerCLI creates/configures VM objects and boots them, 2.) PXE catches initial boot, 3.) Unattended install deploys/configures OS over the network.